Jquery autocomplete with special characters
I'm using the jQuery autocomplete for city names. I had issues with accents and "ç" but it's good now. I still have issues with "-" though.
For example, if the user type "Maisons Laff", I want the suggestion "Maisons-Laffite" to appear. I don't want the user to type the "-".
Here is my code at the moment:
$(function () {
            $("#input_ville").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/get_cities.php',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            query: request.term,
                            table: 'villes_france_free'
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            let normalizedSuggestions = data.suggestions.map(suggestion => ({
                                label: suggestion,
                                value: suggestion,
                                normalized: suggestion.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
                            }));

                            let normalizedQuery = request.term.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');

                            let filteredSuggestions = normalizedSuggestions.filter(suggestion =>
                                suggestion.normalized.toLowerCase().startsWith(normalizedQuery.toLowerCase())
                            );

                            filteredSuggestions = filteredSuggestions.slice(0, 5);

                            response(filteredSuggestions.map(suggestion => suggestion.label));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3
            });
        });

I tried to change my SQL query with REPLACE ()
$sql = "SELECT ville_nom_reel FROM $table WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(ville_nom_reel), '-', '') LIKE ? OR REPLACE(ville_code_postal, '-', '') LIKE ? ORDER BY CASE WHEN ville_nom_reel = ? THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, ville_nom_reel";


But it didn't work. What could I try ? Thank you
